# If I deploy react app on github pages and node.js backend on heroku will it work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, heroku, github-pages

So after a lot of Googling I have found one thing that Github pages does not support anything for a dynamic site having a backend and database its just static.

While Heroku supports Node.js and SQL as backend

So if I deploy my React app on GitHub pages having all my axios Post links pointing to Heroku server where my node.js is deployed with MySQL database will it work ? will my website from GitHub pages able to communicate with node.js backend and retrieve data from database ? any help will be appreciated

Comment: yes it will, as long as the deployed site on GH pages is a static site (SPA/SSG)

Comment: thanks for reply, yes my react app will be static on Github Pages for example my main page is Login page and login button is assigned to axios function for verifying username and password pointing to node.js it will work fine right? just making sure before taking any steps im new into this